# Grouping By A Column For A Total Count in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I am working on a problem for a Intro to Data Science course on Coursera, and I am struggling with adding data to a column in a dataframe.

This is the data set I'm working with:

```
    SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION    STATE   COUNTY  STNAME  CTYNAME     
1   50      3       6           1       1       Alabama Autauga County  
2   50      3       6           1       3       Alabama Baldwin County  
3   50      3       6           1       5       Alabama Barbour County  
4   50      3       6           1       7       Alabama Bibb County
```

What I am trying to do is to insert a column called TotalCounties that has the total count of counties by state as a last column. I've done similar things in SQL, but it doesn't seem to work quite the same in Python.

I have tried the code below, but the column ends up displaying as NaN instead of a number like I want it to.

```py
   counties_only_df = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
   x = counties_only_df.groupby('STNAME').count()['SUMLEV']
   counties_only_df['Total Counties'] = x
```

I would like a number to display in the newly created column instead of NaN.

Comment: Is this what you mean ```counties_only_df['Total Counties'] = counties_only_df.groupby('STNAME').transform('count')```? Or do you want to do something with the County column?

Comment: can you include an explicit desired output?

Comment: @BenPap I actually wanted something with the state name since the state names repeated in the dataset for every county that is in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## try:

```
df['Total Counties'] = df.groupby('STNAME')['STNAME'].transform('count')
```

## change "df" for your DataFrame name

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Thanks! Can you explain why you did the groupby('STNAME')['STNAME']?